# Getting textbox.text in gridview auto generated edit control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox, aspxgridview

Hi i am having a problem using the auto generated edit button in my gridview.

i am trying to get the username from the edit text box and insert it to my database like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="UserNamelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="UserNameEdit" Width="100" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' Enabled="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

c# method that occurs on the update click.

```
    protected void UsersGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{     

    GridViewRow row = UsersGridview.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    Connect c = new Connect("EdenSiteDB.accdb");
    string updatesql = "UPDATE Users Set Username= '" + ((TextBox)row.FindControl("UserNameEdit")).Text + "' , Email= '" + ((TextBox)row.FindControl("EmailEdit")).Text + "' , Admin= " + (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("IsAdminBoxEdit")).Checked).ToString() + " WHERE UserID= " + Session["UserId"].ToString() + ";";
    OleDbCommand updatecmm = new OleDbCommand(updatesql);
    c.TakeAction(updatecmm);

    string usersql = "SELECT * FROM Users;";
    dt = c.MakeConnection(usersql, "Users");
    UsersGridview.EditIndex = -1;
    DataBind();
}
```

While running this is the updatesql:

```
updatesql = "UPDATE Users Set Username= 'edmx0' , Email= 'edmx0.et@gmail.com' , Admin= True WHERE UserID= 17;"
```

these are the previouse values. not the new ones i just entered.

but when i debug it, my sql keeps coming up with the initial username, and not the one i just entered.
I assume it has something to do with my gridview binding at that moment but i don't know how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

can you step through to a breakpoint at the OleDbCommand and post the result of

```
updatesql
```

before the update command runs?

Comment: i hope you meant this (updated the question with what i assumed you asked for)